# Splitting a polygon by another polygon

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics

I need an algorithm for splitting a (convex) polygon (let's call it **base** polygon). The polygon should be splitted into several smaller polygons by another polygon's edges (let's call this one the **splitting** polygon).
I know there exist algorithms for **clipping** a polygon (f.e. the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm), but these algorithms discard the vertices that are lying outside of the splitting polygon instead of creating new polygons with them. I don't want to clip a polygon, i want to split it into several small parts.
I know the answer seems quite obvious because I would just have to extend the existing algorithms.
The problem is that I can't figure out a nice and performant way of doing this.
Are there existing algorithms that describe how to best split a polygon in a performant way?
There has to be a simple solution for this problem that I can't figure out at the moment.

Comment: Can we assume the clipping polygon is not complex?

Comment: Yes, the clipping polygon is always convex.

Comment: "these algorithms discard the vertices that are lying outside of the splitting polygon instead of creating new polygons with them" Not for any good reason; you could easily modify them to save the bits on the other side of the line.

Comment: That's correct. The hard part is to determine which of the vertices outside of the splitting polygon should be connected to a new one. I'm stuck in finding a fast way to connect all the outlying vertices.

Comment: Are both the subject and window (splitting) polygons convex ?

Comment: Yes, they are both convex.

Comment: what about splitting base with every edge of the splitting poly. with every split you should get two polygons. the one outside of the splitting edge should be rejected, the other one should be left for further splitting with remaining edges. finally you get a part of a poly that is covered by splitting poly. the ones that were rejected are what you were looking for. all you need is a function that splits polygon with a plane or line. but this is pretty straightforward to get.

Comment: This is basically a good idea. The problem is that not every split of a splitting polygon's edge with the base polygon must return 2 intersections (and therefore 2 parts of the base polygon). This can happen if the edge of the splitting polygon starts outside and ends inside of the base polygon, where the next edge of the splitting polygon attaches to.

Comment: Since the polys are convex you must have 2 intersections unless your splitting line hit the vertex. However in this case the splitted base is either outside or inside of the splitting edge (or using correct terminology in front of or behind it). Just to clarify: in my approach I am using infinite lines (or planes) for splitting that are determined by the edge.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of clipping against an infinite plane! This would actually make sense. Although this solution results in more polygons (because you split the base polyon by every edge as an infinite plane), but therefore it should be guaranteed that the split polygons are always convex. Nice side-effect! This actually looks like the simple solution I was looking for all the time! Will try it out and report to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this problem as that of finding the intersection of the subject polygon and the **complement** of the window polygon. So you can use the standard [Surtherland-Hodgman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm) algorithm for that purpose, taking two precautions:

1. swap the roles of the subject and the window (actually your window is not convex as you consider its complement, only the subject is convex),
2. embed the window polygon in a large bounding box that covers both polygons, and consider the box as a polygon with a hole.

   [image]

Example: the subject polygon is the rectangle and the window is the pentagon. Form the green polygon (larger rectangle with a hole) and clip it inside the rectangular (convex) window. The result of the clipping is in blue.

With some extra care, it should be possible to do without the large bounding box.